# Create shared memory list of strings for use in pool.map

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

How can I make a list of strings a shared memory object? I have a function that will go through this list and make subsequences of the strings, but when using `pool.map` to make it multithreaded, memory usage exceeds 16Gb RAM. As a result, I would like to make the original list a shared memory object.

I have seen posts showing how to use `Manager` to make a shared memory dictionary or Array to make a shared memory array, but what about a shared memory list?

Comment: Which operating system? On a forking system like linux that has a copy-on-write view of the parent, a list of strings created before execution is already visible. The trick is to put it into a global variable and not pass it to the child in `pool.map`. That doesn't work for windows. though.

Comment: `Manager` creates proxies that try to update all the workers when you change something. They tend to be very expensive. If the strings will fit into fixed-sized blocks, a `multiprocessing.Array` or a `mmap` file work well.

Comment: @tdelaney Linux. What exactly do you mean by "not pass it to the child in pool.map"?

Comment: Suppose I have `big_list` of strings. My worker could work on `global big_list` or I could pass it in the map function `pool.map(f, (arg, big_list) for arg in mydata)`. The first just uses the already existent list in shared memory. The second copies the list.

Comment: Note that you can't change the list. Any change would be in child memory only. (the copy-on-write part).

Comment: @tdelaney even when I do `pool.map(fxn, big_list)`, where big_list is a globally defined object, the list is copied to each thread. I am not writing to `big_list` at all though. Any ideas?

Comment: `pool.map(fxn, big_list)` passes each item in `big_list` to one of the workers. To reduce handshake time, it will "chunk" `big_list`. If you have 4 workers, it will send the first 1/4 of the list to process A, and etc.... all at once. You get a copy of 1/4 of the list in each worker. Set `chunksize=n` to send less at a time. For a cpu intensive calculation `chunksize=1` is reasonable because its work dwarfs the extra overhead.